Can CatBoostRegressor handle multi-output regression problem?
I'm trying to regress the muti—degree output on the muti-degree feature, but I keep getting an error at loss_function.

_catboost.CatBoostError: catboost/private/libs/options/loss_description.cpp:20: multi loss is
not supported

I would like to know if the model can handle multi-output regression problems, and if so, how to do it.
